# JOptionPane to appear on selected JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Hi all I  am having some difficulties with adding a joptionpane in JcheckBox listener

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {

            if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    ///some code

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Message", "Alert",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

so it works fine,but the problem is that the JCheckBox gets selected and immediately deselected how can I manage to fix this ?

Cheers

Comment: I am curious to know what the "some code" does. Are you sure you're not accedentally changing the state of the checkbox there?

Comment: Which is why a SSCCE: http://sscce.org should be posted with every question, so we don't have to guess what "some code" is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestions here (solution) to use an action listener instead of a item listener. This does work, however, I though it strange given that all the texts I have suggest an item listener is the expected type of listener for a check box.

In fact, this is a known bug as acknowledged by [Oracle Bug ID:6924233](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6924233) The JOptionPane apparently causes another event to be generated.

The recommended fix is to invoke the JOptionPane using invokeLater. This works fine and involves only a minor code change to a program already using an item listener for other purposes.

Comment: you are right please post this one an answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282488/where-is-lost-setselected-from-jcheckbox , because this post could be closed again +1

Answer (score 2):

The problem must be in "///some code" as the following test program works for me in Java 6:

```
public class CheckBoxItemListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Click me");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Item Listener");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
        frame.add(checkBox);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Message", "Alert",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Have a look in the omitted code for setSelected or doClick calls.

Comment: Well, it seams that the problem is not in the code I tested my code on my Linux and it works, but I am developing the app on a virtual machine Windows XP and it seams this is the problem. I don't know why but under my XP the code is selecting the checkBox and deselecting it. Does anyone have a clue why?