# What is the difference between getItem(), getSelectableItem() and getSource()?

Tags: java, swing, events, jcheckbox, itemlistener

I don't really understand the difference between the following methods for an ItemEvent object, especially in the code example below:

`Object getItem()` from class *ItemEvent*, Java-API:

> Returns the item affected by the event.

`ItemSelectable getItemSelectable()` from class *ItemEvent*, Java-API:

> Returns the originator of the event.

`Object getSource()` inherited from class *EventObject*, Java-API:

> Returns the object on which the Event initially occurred.

What I know is, that `getItemSelectable()` simplifies getting the object, because I do not have to cast explicitly to use methods like `getText()`. (So the `(JCheckBox)` cast in the second `println` command is not necessary.) And I know, that `getItemSelectable()` uses `getSource()`. **But why is there another `getItem()`?**

But the example below does not show any difference between those methods:

```
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("text of checkbox", true);

ItemListener myListener = new ItemListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(((JCheckBox) e.getItem()).getText());
            System.out.println(((JCheckBox) e.getSource()).getText());
            System.out.println(((JCheckBox) e.getItemSelectable()).getText());
        }
    };

cb.addItemListener(myListener);
```

Output:

> text of checkbox
>
> text of checkbox
>
> text of checkbox

So what is the exact difference and when do I use which function?

Edit: Maybe there is no difference, at least no conceptual difference (except of return type and original class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the definition of the `ItemEvent` constructor :

```
 /**
 * Constructs an <code>ItemEvent</code> object.
 * <p> This method throws an
 * <code>IllegalArgumentException</code> if <code>source</code>
 * is <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @param source The <code>ItemSelectable</code> object
 *               that originated the event
 * @param id           The integer that identifies the event type.
 *                     For information on allowable values, see
 *                     the class description for {@link ItemEvent}
 * @param item   An object -- the item affected by the event
 * @param stateChange  An integer that indicates whether the item was
 *               selected or deselected.
 *                     For information on allowable values, see
 *                     the class description for {@link ItemEvent}
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>source</code> is null
 * @see #getItemSelectable()
 * @see #getID()
 * @see #getStateChange()
 */
public ItemEvent(ItemSelectable source, int id, Object item, int stateChange) {
    super(source, id);
    this.item = item;
    this.stateChange = stateChange;
}
```

The `ItemSelectable source` parameter is the element that will be returned by `e.getSource()`. The `Object item` parameter is the element that will be returned by `e.getItem()`.

So actually the question is when the constructor is called with different object for `source` and `item`?

Looking at the `JCheckBox` super classes - `JToggleButton` and `AbstractButton`, the ItemEvent is always constructed with the same object for both parameter. So maybe in some custom implementation the use of these differents methods make sense.

Comment: When `e.getItemSelectable()` uses `getSource()`, it also means that `e.getItemSelectable()` and `e.getItem()` do return different objects. That's interesting because it is not that obvious I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see the description here... [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html)

Comment: Hm. I don't get it. It's definitely not a string that is returned when a JCheckBox is firing the event, although I get three times the same output with getText()..

Comment: `ItemListener` always firing two events `SELECTED` and `DESELECTED` and [read my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282488/where-is-lost-setselected-from-jcheckbox), maybe will help you