# How to show that JRadio button is selected and deselected?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane, jradiobutton

I have 5 JRadio buttons on my swing application. When I click my Jradio button. I have created a joption dialogue to display that it is clicked. But when I unselect it it also displays that it is selected. What is the problem?
One of my Jradio button coding.

```
      private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"one is selected");
}
```

So I finally got answer

with help of @Neil Locketz

```
     private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
     {
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected())
          {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"one is selected");
          }
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: With that piece of code, it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: if Neil helped you, please upvote and accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the JRadioButton Object so you can call button.isSelected() this will return a boolean of whether or not the button that you are testing is selected.

Answer (score 2):

- not possible directly, have to wrap, delay this event for showing a `JOptionPane` inside `invokeLater()`
- this is [Bug for Java6 versions 6924233 : JOptionPane inside JCheckBox itemListener causes setSelected(false)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6924233)
- [more in my (similair???) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282488/why-does-setselected-on-jcheckbox-lose-effect)

Comment: +1 for digging up the issue. Though, it isn't virulent here because the OP is using an ActionListener, not an ItemListener. On the other hand: that's only coincidental - as there's no guarantee on listener notification sequence. So another (virtual :-) +1 for carefully thinking of invokeLater!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this is totally pseudo-code

```
     JRadioButton testButton1=new JRadioButton("button1");
     JRadioButton testButton2=new JRadioButton("button2");

     ButtonGroup btngroup=new ButtonGroup();  

     btngroup.add(testButton1);  
     btngroup.add(testButton2);  

     boolean test;

     foreach(JRadioButton b in btngroup){
        test = b.isSelected();
        if(test)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b.getValue() + "is selected");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create one single `ActionListener` instance and add it to all your buttons. Something like this:

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("1");
JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("2");
JRadioButton radio3 = new JRadioButton("3");
group.add(radio);
group.add(radio2);
group.add(radio3);
ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
        System.out.println(source.getText() + " selected " + source.isSelected());
    }
};
radio.addActionListener(a);
radio2.addActionListener(a);
radio3.addActionListener(a);
```