# Java JCheckBox ItemListener makes program work incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I minimized my program to include only the problem and I tried to code exactly as I understood from many examples. When I used the `ActionListener`, I get problem solved. But I wonder why using `ItemListener`, checkbox does not operate correctly.
If I run my program without `ItemListener`, it works correctly. With this `ItemListener`, checkBox doesn't change state.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class omaJFrame extends JFrame{
    private JCheckBox checkBox1;

    public omaJFrame() {
        super("Window Title");

        TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Checkbox 1");
        add(checkBox1);
        checkBox1.addItemListener(handler); 
    }

    private class TheHandler implements ItemListener {
        String output = "";

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getItem()==checkBox1)
                output = String.format("%s", checkBox1.isSelected());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output); 
        }
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class EventHandlerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        omaJFrame window = new omaJFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(350,200);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291984/655249

Comment: possible duplicate of [JOptionPane to appear on selected JCheckBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532941/joptionpane-to-appear-on-selected-jcheckbox)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Note also that Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OmaJFrame extends JFrame {

    private JCheckBox checkBox1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OmaJFrame f = new OmaJFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public OmaJFrame() {
        super("Window Title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Checkbox 1");
        add(checkBox1);
        checkBox1.addItemListener(handler);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TheHandler implements ItemListener {

        String output = "";

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getItem() == checkBox1) {
                output = String.format("%s", checkBox1.isSelected());
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in line: JOptionPane.showMessage..., If I comment that away, checkbox works!

Comment: @PaulaPosio You can still use the option pane too, if you want, if you wrap it with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (or `EventQueue.invokeLater()`).

Comment: @kiheru: That's the workaround suggested in bug id [6924233](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291984/655249) cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291984/230513).

Comment: @trashgod yep. Did't know there's a recommended workaround until reading serg.nechaev's comment. Just seemed an obvious way to get around spurious events.